# Apache CXF Endpoint validation with Interceptor

Tags: web-services, cxf, apache-camel, interceptor

### What I want to do:

Implement a [Camel route](http://camel.apache.org/routes.html) from a [CXF Endpoint](http://camel.apache.org/cxf.html) to an [JMS queue](http://camel.apache.org/jms.html) with schema validation in CXF endpoint.

**Validation is enabled in CXF endpoint:**

```
/* Set endpoint properties */
Map<String, Object> propertiesMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
propertiesMap.put("schema-validation-enabled", "true");

/* Create endpoint */
CxfEndpoint cxfEndpoint = new CxfEndpoint();
cxfEndpoint.setWsdlURL("wsdl/input.wsdl");
cxfEndpoint.setDataFormat(DataFormat.CXF_MESSAGE);
cxfEndpoint.setProperties(propertiesMap);
cxfEndpoint.getInInterceptors().add(new FaultInterceptor());
```

**The Camel route:**

```
from(cxfEndpoint)
.routeId("INPUT_ROUTE")
.to("jms:foo.bar");
```

**The CXF interceptor:**

```
public class FaultInterceptor extends AbstractSoapInterceptor {

  private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(FaultInterceptor.class);

  public FaultInterceptor() {
    super(Phase.UNMARSHAL);
  }

  public void handleMessage(SoapMessage message) throws Fault {
    LOGGER.info("handleMessage=" + message.getExchange().getInMessage());    
  }

  @Override
  public void handleFault(SoapMessage message) {
    Fault fault = (Fault) message.getContent(Exception.class);
    LOGGER.info("handleFault='" + fault + "'");   
    /* Add some header property that says the message is invalid */  
  }

}
```

### Problem:

The works ok if I send a valid SOAP message. If I send an invalid SOAP message, the `handleFault` method kicks in, logs the fault and that's all.
For the invalid SOAP message scenario, is it possible that I can log the fault with `handleFault` method and still route the invalid message to the JMS queue?
This is the only interceptor I've added to the endpoint.

### I'm using:

- Apache ServiceMix 5.0.0
- Apache Camel 2.12.3
- Apache CXF 2.7.10

Answer (score 0):

You can't do a try/catch statement since the error happends in the "from" clause.

However, you can use a [Dead Letter Channel](http://camel.apache.org/dead-letter-channel.html).

```
errorHandler(deadLetterChannel("jms:foo.bar.invalid"));

from(cxfEndpoint)
 .routeId("INPUT_ROUTE")
 .to("jms:foo.bar");
```

Comment: I've added the errorHandler but nothing changed, I still get the error in Karaf `Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-datatype-valid.1.2.1: 'go' is not a valid value for 'integer'.` and no message routing to the invalid queue.